# C++14: enumeration previously declared with fixed underlying type: different behavior between compilers

Tags: c++, enums, c++14, language-lawyer

Sample code:

```
enum E : char;
enum E;
```

Invocations:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c
<nothing>

$ clang++ -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c
<source>:2:6: error: enumeration previously declared with fixed underlying type

$ icc -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -c
<nothing>

$ cl /std:c++14 /Za
<source>(2): error C3432: 'E': a forward declaration of an unscoped enumeration must have an underlying type
<source>(2): error C3433: 'E': all declarations of an enumeration must have the same underlying type, was 'char' now 'int'
```

Is this code well-formed?

What the standard says?

Comment: Looks like it depends on what type is used for the underlying type of the unscoped enumeration: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/enum#dcl.enum-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [[dcl.enum]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.enum#3):

> An unscoped enumeration shall not be later redeclared as scoped and **each redeclaration shall include an enum-base specifying the same underlying type as in the original declaration.**

Emphasis added. Clang is correct.